# Trying to write some code to determine if a box has been checked in html pages

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am working with a large collection of documents that are prepared by more than 5K different entities.  One of the things I am trying to do is to determine whether or not a box has been checked.  The preparer needs to indicate some information by checking one of five different boxes.

The problem is that the preparer decided on their own how to present a check box in the html.  Some of their representations are interesting.  They mostly rely on wingdings as the font directive.  Here are a few of the types of checked boxes I have found so far

```
'serif">S</font>'
'wingdings">x</font>'
'&#252;' 
'&#253;'
'&#254;'


<font style="font-family: Wingdings; font-variant: normal">&#254;</font>
```

The piece of code that I pasted above will display a checked box when the document is opened with a variant of IE, it will render something else when the document is opened with Firefox, Safari or Chrome.

Here is another example

```
<div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman">THE DATA THAT HAS THE CHECKED BOX  <font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: wingdings 2, serif">R</font></font></div>
```

So I guess in its simplest form my question is

Is there something in python that 'knows' that

```
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: wingdings 2, serif">R</font>
```

this is a checked box?  And then extending that further - is there something that 'knows' this for just about every way a checked box can be presented in html code?

I want to note that when I check the text of that font element I get a unicode R

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: does not make any sense to we what you are asking. Rephrase your question please and come to the point with less blabla...what is the exact problem - bring it down to two sentences.

Comment: rather if anyone has another way I can think about this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your real problem? bring it down to two sentences...

Comment: How to check to see if the checkbox is checked

Comment: What is the problem with using a parser like BeautifulSoup and iterating over the input elements and checking the CHECKED attribute?

Comment: -1 for the very poor quality of the question

Comment: Once again: what is the problem? Do you expect that we write two lines of LXML code with a path expression return all input nodes? This is homework...LXML has a very good documentation..so where is the exact problem?

Comment: """Thanks for your thoughts""" - is this is only comment you want to leave here? If you ask for help, then please provide exact information what you are actually doing and where the specific problem is.

Comment: Well the alternative is to respond like you have responded.  I am sorry I am not as smart as you are, for example I did not now that BeautifulSoup can catch a checked box when the code to indicate the checked box is <div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman">[&#8730;]</font></div>  I am missing something in the documentation and am going back through it again just in case you are correct I don't think you are but I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Please **update** your question, rather than just add comments.  Please edit and focus the question.  It appears you have lots of HTML files and you want help parsing them.  Correct?  Please **update** the question to precisely (and briefly) and accurately describe your real problem.

Comment: There is nothing in Python, or AFAIK, any other language that knows that "R" should be interpreted as Box Checked. ( How or why would it know ? ) You'll have to handle that special case yourself by looking for FONT-FAMILY: wingdings.

Comment: @Steven  Kind sir, I believe I figured it out.  Check my answer below please to see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it appears like this.

The ascii value of 'S' is 83.  If you look up 83 on wingdings, you get "droplet".  The Unicode equivalent of "droplet" is .

The ascii value of 'x' is 120.  Looking 120 up on wingdings, you get "clear".  Unicode ⌧.

252 is wingding "checkbld", unicode ✓.

253 is wingding "boxxmarkbld", unicode ☒

254 is wingding "boxcheckbld", unicode ☑.

'R' is displayed under font-family wingdings2, ascii 82, and unicode equivalent ☑

Note:  This is just a guess on which is which.  Don't take my word for it.
I assumed it would be so since it seems to make sense.  My source is [Here (wingdings)](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html) and [Here (wingdings2)](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html)

Solution to comment:  [√] (left bracket, amp, pound, 8730, semicolon, right bracket).
√ is interpreted as U+221A, with the semicolon being an "end statement" type character.  According to [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm), U+221A is the square root symbol, and is in python u'\u221a'.  This should solve your problem.

All answers I give are a matter of pure speculation and guesswork, although character codes and equivalents are verified through the links and python2.7.1's chr() and ord().